# How to implement the sharing of invites to join the app from inside the app to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I want to invite new users to my app from within the app via and want to share them the Link to redirect users to playstore to install the app via Whatsapp.
(Share on Whatsapp Functionality)
The problem:

1. I want to share an image about the app and also a link in the caption for sharing on Whatsapp. I have established the deep links however I am unable to share the image along with the caption from within the app to invite more users.

Tech Stack: React Native and Expo

Answer (score 0):

React Native Social sharing support only text. In case you want a social share card with an image, caption, and link. You need to have a simple webpage with server-side rendering and you can define any Open Graph Metadata you want like images, text, video, and more.

WhatsApp or any social network will crawl and render a nice-looking card with all metadata you specified.

You can read more about Open Graph metadata here https://ogp.me/